# Windows 8 tablet picture password

Tags: windows-8

I accidentally got my picture password wrong too many times and I am wondering instead of typing a password in if there is a way to get back to the picture.

Comment: Unlikely since its a security feature which would be useless if you got unlimited tries

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to log in with your text password and reset the picture password from the Users setting.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Sign-in Options on the logon screen, you'll find at least an alternative option to log in to your Microsoft account or local account using regular text password. If you can't remember the passwords of any sign-in options, you need to take advantage of some password recovery software such as PCUnlocker or Ophcrack.